# PreProcessor constant for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I have received a project from a partner and I tried to compile and deploy it in my device. However the build fails because a const value seems undefined.

```
#if !defined(MXD_OS_WINDOWS_PHONE)
    uResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(uCount, ahWatch, FALSE, INFINITE);
#else
  uResult = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(uCount, ahWatch, false, INFINITE, true);
#endif
```

When I search my workspace I can find a value that the MXD_OS_WINDOWS_PHONE is being defined. For example there is no line

```
#define MXD_OS_WINDOWS_PHONE 1
```

Is there any way to define the value in a project file? Is this mandatory the value to be defined?

Comment: What is the point of testing for an undefined constant if the build will fail when it's undefined!?

Comment: The target is windows phone and some header files are being included if this constant is set to true. So it is quite strange that the definition is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to open the project settings -> compile tab  -> conditional symbol
[image: Project Settings]

(sorry for Visual Studio in Italian)